# How to assign $arr_date to a while loop?

Tags: php, arrays, date, object, foreach

This is the result of `$arr_date`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2008-08-20
            [page_views] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2011-05-03
            [page_views] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2011-09-05
            [page_views] => 4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2011-10-11
            [page_views] => 2
        )

)
```

How to put my array `$arr_date` here in the while loop? **This is not working yet.**

```
while (true) {
        $page_ctr++;
        if (date('Y-m', strtotime($arr_date)) > date('Y-m')) {
            $total_pages = $page_ctr;
            break;
        }

 }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @pekka i receive an error if i put my foreach $arr_date inside while loop.

Comment: where did you get this array of objects? from database? why don't you get an array of arrays then, if you aren't familiar with classes?

Answer (score 0):

Try foreach loop like this

```
$page_ctr = 1;$total_pages=0;
foreach ($arr_date as $k=>$v)
{
  if (date('Y-m', strtotime($v->date)) > date('Y-m')) {
    $total_pages += $page_ctr;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: then define `$total_pages =''` before foreach. you must be receiving `notice` not an `error`

Answer (score 0):

When using objects, you must use object calls.
example

```
$object -> objectcontent
```

in your case it will be

```
$arr_date[0]->date
```

Have a look at this

```
    //Defining my object to look like yours. I just set the year to 2012 so the while will succeed.
$array = array("date" => "2012-10-20", "page_views" => 2);
    $object = (object) $array;
    $arr_date[] = $object;

//Making an increment variabel
        $i = 0;
        while (true) {

            $page_ctr++;
    //Setting my array $arr_date to iterate through the increment variabel, and output the objects content with the name date
            if (date('Y-m', strtotime($arr_date[$i]->date)) > date('Y-m')) {

                    $total_pages = $page_ctr;

                break;
            }
//Increasing my increment variabel.
            $i++;

     }
     //printing the total pages.
     print $total_pages;
```

Yet, if i were you, i would use a foreach loop wich iterates better through an array

```
//Setting increment variable $page_ctr to zero
$page_ctr = 0; 
//Starting foreach array and asking the arrays key value to be set in $key and the value to
//be set in $value. in this case $value will be the object
foreach ($arr_date as $key=>$value) {   
//increasing the increment variable by one
     $page_ctr++;   
//checking your objects date against the current date to see if its bigger.
     if (date('Y-m', strtotime($value->date)) > date('Y-m')) {
       $total_pages = $page_ctr;
//Breaking
       break;
     }

}
```

This is a copy-paste ready code for testing and seeing for yourself.

```
<?php
$array = array("date" => "2012-10-20", "page_views" => 2);
$object = (object) $array;
$arr_date[] = $object;

$page_ctr = 0; 
$total_pages = 0;

foreach ($arr_date as $key=>$value) {   

     $page_ctr++;   

     if (date('Y-m', strtotime($value->date)) > date('Y-m')) {
       $total_pages = $page_ctr;

       break;
     }

}

 print $total_pages;


?>
```

Comment: You must define $total_pages as a variabel. Try writing $total_pages = 0; underneath $page_ctr = 0;

Comment: It's just continue to loop an exceed to 30 sec limit.

Comment: It might do with the While loop, but not with the foreach loop. The whileloop will keep running if there is no date bigger than the date today. Try changing the object date to "2012-08" instead of "2010-08" and you will se it works.

I would prefer using the foreach loop, i editet my post to see how it will work, you can simply copy paste the code and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your actual *overall* problem is that you try to solve, but you could encapsulate your date selecting problem into an array filter and then just pick what you need. Take care you don't create an endless loop, in any case:

```
class ArrayCallbackFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    private $param;
    private $callback;
    public function __construct($param, $callback, Array $array)
    {
        $this->param = $param;
        $this->callback = $callback;
        $iterator = new ArrayIterator($array);
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }
    public function accept()
    {
        $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        $func = $this->callback;
        return (bool) $func($this->param, $current);
    }
}

$dateIsLarger = function($date, $object)
{
    return (date('Y-m', strtotime($object->date)) > $date);
};


$date = date('Y-m');
$total_pages = FALSE;
$page_ctr = 0;
while (true) {

        $page_ctr++;

        foreach(new ArrayCallbackFilter($date, $dateIsLarger, $dates) as $object)
        {
            $total_pages = $page_ctr;
            break 2; # <<-- break the right level
        }
        throw new Exception('Endless Loop.');
}
```

[Demo/Sandbox](http://codepad.viper-7.com/42Yhso) to play around for yourself.